# When to use the TestProperty-Attribute in the Silverlight Unit Test Framework?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

The other Attributes (aka. `TestMethod`, `ExpectedException`, etc.) I know where and when to use, but I don´t know what I can do with the `TestProperty`-Attribute.

Why should I use it and when? Whats the reason for this attribute?

I found no useful documentation on the Internet, that explains the `TestProperty`-Attribute. And intellisense doesn´t provide useful information. The documentation of the Toolkit provides no documentation for the Unit Test Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testpropertyattribute.aspx) may be of some help. A usage example is given in which the unit tests reads some custom attributes set using the [TestProperty] tag.

Comment: @ Thanks, i didn´t found that on MSDN. The section 'The TestContext Class' on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770525.aspx provides also additional information